# InvalidArgumentException in Manager.php line 90

Tags: php, laravel-5

this is service.php

```js
 'weixinweb'=>[
            'client_id' => env('WEIXIN_KEY')
            'client_secret' =>env('WEIXIN_SECRET'),
            'redirect' => env('WEIXIN_REDIRECT'),
        ],
```

this is  routes.php

```js
Route::get('/weixinweb/', 'Auth\AuthController@weixinweb');//add
Route::get('/weixinweb/callback/','Auth\AuthController@weixinwebcallback');/add
```

this is  eventserviceprovide.php

```js
'SocialiteProviders\Manager\SocialiteWasCalled' => [
       'SocialiteProviders\WeixinWeb\WeixinWebExtendSocialite@handle',//add
    ]
```

```html
InvalidArgumentException in Manager.php line 90: 
Driver [weixin web] not supported.
```

the result

Comment: I'm having a similar problem - did you ever find a solution?